# Can I assume that a 64 bit number is the pruduct of two 32 bit numbers?

Tags: security, math, rsa, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to make a brute force program to guess and check numbers until I find two unknown prime numbers that multiply to a known number. But when the known number is 64 bits long its inefficient to start from 3x5, 3x7 etc. so I made this formula to find the two numbers I should start with. Here `m` is the known product and to get the two numbers, I start with either adding one or subtracting one at the end. The idea is to use log2 and round up to find the number of bits the product uses and divide by two and subtract one to find the number of bits the multiples use.
Is this formula right though?
Can i assume that a 64 bit number is a multiple of two 32 bit prime numbers?
Or is that bad to assume?

To avoid having to start with 2x3, 2x5, 2x7, 2x11 when dealing with 64 bit numbers I tried to make a formula to figure out which numbers I could start with. I came up with this formula[image]
Here I find the number of bits the product (m) uses (log2(m) rounded up), divide it by two and subtract one to get what I think is the smallest number of bits the two prime factors could use. Tthen I add or subtract one at the end to find the two numbers I start with. But now I have doubts, because what if the large prime number is just 2x[enormous prime number]?

Comment: *"but when the known number is 64 bits long its dumb to start from 3x5"* Why? 15 is a perfectly valid 64-bit number. Now, if you know any of the upper 32 bits are set (or, really, any of the upper 60 bits), you know the value isn't 15, but... (I'm assuming unsigned here.)

Comment: Please use proper capitalization when posting. it greatly helps with readability.

Comment: what im basically trying to do is make a brute force program to crack REALLY low rsa ey lenghts and in rsa dont the prime numbers p and q tend to be the same bit lenght for more security, since having a big difference would make it easier to factorise?

Comment: Security methods usually intentionally go away from anything close to the square root of the product, precisely because of your approach. But probably not as far as down to 3 or 5, I agree.

Comment: Please define your understanding of "64 bit number". Would that be one with bit 63 set? I ask because I am somewhat with TJ. In your context however describing e.g. "51" as a 64bit value in the sense of 64bit security is odd. But even in your reading, a 64bit number would not necessarily be 32x32. It could also be 33x31, 34x30 and again probably not 61x3.

Comment: Mathias: RSA factors nowadays usually _are_ the same size but they don't have to be. They _must not_ be nearly equal; _that_ allows efficient factoring, and as an overkill method to prevent this the original (CACM) paper actually recommended p and q _differ_ in (decimal) length by 'a few digits'. Each factor must be 'sufficiently' large, and _must_ be odd (i.e. not 2). If you don't require the same size you can get n-bit product from n/2-bit times n/2+1-bit e.g. 0xabcd0003 * 0x12345000d = 0xc378554d23380027. ...

Comment: ... But no one has _ever_ used 64-bit RSA. Even the CACM paper effectively specified at least 330 bits, and no serious implementation has used less than 512; nowadays the standard is 2048. Even for 512, bruteforcing all potential primes (say, 1 and 5 mod 6) from 2^255 to 2^256 won't finish in this universe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean "64 bit number" as something with bit 63 set, maybe bit 63 not set but bit 62 set; and I am with you in that, in the context of something that is described as 64bit security. Likewise you then probably mean "32bit number" with a bit set around 31 or 30.

In short the answer, even with that assumption, is "No".

Because the product can be asymmetric, e.g. a "34bit number" x "30bit number", or 36bit x 28bit.
And from what I know, security methods usually intentionally go away from anything close to the square root of the product, precisely to avoid optimisations like your approach. Though not as far as 60bit x 4bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assume both factors will be 32 bit. All you know about the factors of a 64 bit odd positive composite number greater than 2 is that it will have at least one non-trivial positive factor less than or equal to its square root which will be < 2^32. If it doesn't, it is prime.

What you are trying to do is called integer factorization. It is a well studied subject with lots of related algorithms. If you do not know for sure if the number is composite or not, there are fast ways to check if the number is prime, which you should do before trying to find factors.

For 64 bit numbers, you can efficiently factorize using a combination of trial division of potential 32bit divisors and Pollard-Rho which is a probabalistic factoring algorithm which is quite simple to code and efficient on small numbers while being much faster in the general case than trial division for numbers above some threshold which will be somewhere below 64 bit.